# SAP GUI install that will create a directory and copy the file in an SCCM install

Tags: powershell, directory, copy, sccm, sap-gui

I have tested this code locally and it works fine to create a directory and add the .xml files needed.  For some reason when packaging it in SCCM it seems to have problems copying the files into the client directory it is doing the installs on.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
ForEach($User in $Users) {

    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\$User\AppData\Roaming\" -Name "SAP\Common" -ItemType "directory" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Copy-item "\\SCCMServer\C'$\Filepath\SAPUILandscape.xml" -destination "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common"
    Copy-item "\\SCCMServer\c'$\Filepath\SAPUILandscapeGlobal.xml" -destination "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common"

}
```

Comment: please add the error you get when you try to run that code ... put it in the Question & wrap it in code formatting markers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single-quote character in your source path between `c` and `$`. If you want to escape the `$` you should use the backtick character `` ` ``

`"\\SCCMServer\c'$\Filepath\SAPUILandscapeGlobal.xml"`
`"\\SCCMServer\c'$\Filepath\SAPUILandscapeGlobal.xml"`